# SQL job failing only on particular instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have an application ,where the session data of the application is stored in a table, from that table we have a SQL job which places the above data in one  more table segregating it more meaningfully.

When we created the job ,the job passed in DEV environment and TEST ,but when we implemented the job  in production and stage, the job is failing with below error.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

We tried restoring the DB to some other instance other than where the application DB resides and the SQL job is completing successfully. The Job is failing only in the instance where application DB resides.

Steps what we tried:
We tried comparing the SQL configuration of the instances where the job completed successfully to the instance where it is failing, no differences
we tried executing the stored proc manually writing some print statements to see if it really a code issue, this didn't helped us since the job is not failing for a particular session GUID and the same step is passing in DEV environment.

We are not able to figure out why this is happening only on instances where application DB resides.

Comment: Can you post some of the data that causes the error?

Comment: Could different `locale`s be at the core of the problem? Have you identified exactly which date conversion did not work and what the date string looked like?

Comment: To Add more: I believe code is not the problem ,since when we restored the entire DB to some other instance and ran the stored proc ,the SP completed successfully,which ruled out code issues.

Comment: The job uses cursor to fetch data row by row from session table to history table,we are not sure why the job is failing at prod and stage application DB instances,we checked collation level which is same as DEV and other instances where the job is passing

Answer (score 0):

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". This is error is based on data. It has a string which is not in required format to be converted to a data. The issue is not with code, its with data. Add a preprocessing step to convert data to requires format.

Comment: The same conversion is happening for the same session guid in DEV

Comment: Data in Dev will be different than data in production.

Answer (score 0):

Check the default language of the server account the job is being run under - my guess would be something similar to DEV/TEST's account being set to British English while LIVE is set to English.
However, even if that is the case, this still only indicates why the issue appears on LIVE. The underlying thing you should do to correct this is make sure that your job makes no assumptions about date formats, does not do any implicit date conversions, and holds dates in date variables/columns, not character ones.

Comment: The collation is also same as DEV/TEST,we are not sure why the particular SP is throwing the error in Live,also point to note is when we restore in some other instance other than application DB instance and run the SP with same data ,the sp is completing,when we restored the same DB with some other name say(app_temp) on the same instance of application DB ,it is failing again with same error.

Comment: I'm not referring to the collation, but the service account the job is executing under.